# How to Efficiently obtain the Eigenvectors and Eigenenergies of a Banded, Hermitian matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am trying to diagonalize a banded, hermitian matrix as efficiently as possible. The specific matrix I am currently trying to diagonalize is a 3200x3200 Hermitian banded matrix and I want to find the corresponding eigenvalues **and** eigenvectors. The matrix is very sparse and only the 1st-3rd diagonal and the 80th diagonal are non-zero. I call the matrix H. I am currently using scipy.linalg.eigh(H) to obtain the eigenvalues/-vectors, but this does not really make use of the sparseness of H. I tried using scipy.linalg.eig_banded, but that performs even worse. Is there an effective algorithm to compute this problem, preferably in python? It would be great if I could speed this problem up. Thank you already in advance!

I am adding a minimal reproducible example below. N_tot is the dimension of the matrix and in the end, I am interested in N_tot ~ 3200. Any help would be HIGHLY appreciated :D

```
import scipy.linalg as linalg
import numpy as np

N = 3200
N_band_max = int(np.sqrt(N/2))*2


Main = np.random.random(N)
Diag1 = np.random.random(N-1) + 1j*np.random.random(N-1)
Diag2 = np.random.random(N-2) + 1j*np.random.random(N-2)
Diag3 = np.random.random(N-N_band_max) + 1j*np.random.random(N-N_band_max)


H = np.diag(Main) + np.diag(Diag1,1) + np.diag(Diag1.conjugate(),-1) + np.diag(Diag2,2) + np.diag(Diag2.conjugate(),-2) + np.diag(Diag3,N_band_max) + np.diag(Diag3.conjugate(),-N_band_max)

EigVals,EigVecs = linalg.eigh(H)
```

Comment: `H_sparse = scipy.sparse.csr(H)` and `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(H_sparse)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(H_sparse)` only calculates a few Eigenvalues (standard 6). The function unfortunately can not calculate all N =3200 Eigenvalues and I need all of them. And if I calculate, say, only 1000, then the sparse eigsh is already way slower that the original.

Comment: My only other suggestion would be `np.linalg.svd(H, compute_uv=False, hermitan=True)` although it's probably not going to be faster (should be more numerically stable though)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, it takes about the same time (even slightly longer :/).

Comment: `H = H.astype( np.complex64 )` (or Main and Diags `.astype( np.float32 )`) is about 1/3 faster, 21 sec -> 14 sec on my old 4-core iMac. Could you point to other matrices e.g. in SuiteSparse ?

Comment: Hey! Sorry for replying only now and thanks for the answer! There is indeed a speedup, I will test, whether the accuracy is sufficient for my current problem. Thx!

How do I use SuiteSparse?